# Using SSL3 from Azure Functions to Call External API

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, azure-functions

We have a .NET application that needs to interact with an API that strictly requires SSL3 for the API to work, however we do not want our whole site to operate within that Security Protocol.

To achieve that in .NET framework, we used [AppDomain and, therefore, remoting](https://bitlush.com/blog/executing-code-in-a-separate-application-domain-using-c-sharp). However, **we are porting our app to .NET Core 2.0** and that functionality is no longer available to us.

Our proposed solution is to use Azure Functions to have a serverless function that can contact the API and return the results of the interaction and therefore act as a proxy.

Here is some of the code that we are setting in our function:

```cs
// set the protocol to SSL3 app wide
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
// ignore any SSL errors
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

However running it gives us the following error:

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
   at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface SecModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SecureCredential scc)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SecureCredential& secureCredential)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Submission#0.<Run>d__1.MoveNext() in :line 15
```

Is it possible to have Azure Functions perform what we are trying to do or are the settings we are trying to set not being honored in the sand-boxed environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Functions runs on top of Windows workers, just like Web Apps do since they're all part of App Service. It's the same sandbox underneath.

If you PowerShell [your way around the registry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245030/how-to-restrict-the-use-of-certain-cryptographic-algorithms-and-protoc) in Kudu you'll find out SSL 3.0 is disabled system-wide, which is expected for **any** modern service.

[image: SSL 3.0 Registry Keys]

From Ivan Ristić's excellent *Bulletproof SSL and TLS* book:

> **DisabledByDefault** — This setting is for applications that do not explicitly configure enabled protocols but use system defaults. If the entry is not present or if the value is 0, the protocol is enabled by default. **If the value is 1, the protocol is disabled by default.** Normally, Windows will disable SSL 2 and leave all other protocols enabled.

Whoever runs the SSL 3.0-only API has taken way too many vacation days in the last 10 years. Talk some sense into those people. SSL 3.0 is vulnerable to the BEAST attack, there's no AES in Microsoft's implementation, no support for the GCM, SHA256 and SHA384 suites and no elliptic curve cryptography, so no forward secrecy.

If you have no trouble sleeping at night taking a dependency on SSL 3.0 you'll have to use a [different TLS library](https://github.com/openssl-net/openssl-net) from the one provided by .NET/Windows (System.Security and SCHANNEL). OpenSSL, BoringSSL, GnuTLS, LibreSSL they're all options if you find a C# wrapper or you have enough time on your hands to roll your own.

The real solution here is to proxy all requests through a Virtual Machine. You control the OS, you control the TLS stack. You can then speak SSL 3.0 to your remote. I can't believe i'm saying this - give me their phone number!

UPDATE: You can now use a (much more) lightweight container instance to proxy SSL 3.0 traffic. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-overview